# Remove rotten mail post

Tags: concrete, post, mailbox

I have to remove the rotten mail post and install a new one. 
The post was broken. I have to take it out first.

The difficult thing is that the concrete around the post root. It's deep and hard. I bought chisel and drill bit for concrete. But it is too tough. After two days it still no lucky.

Hiring a handyman is still not my first choice. Any idea to crush the concrete?

Comment: Any reason you can’t move left or right and dig a new hole?

Comment: Yes, I can but the existing hole's location is perfect.

Comment: Can you dig the rotten wood out of the concrete and then insert a new pole in the same hole?

Comment: I’d dig a hole beside the existing one to give enough room to free the concrete chunk from the old hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool of choice here is a jackhammer.  Today's electric ones will do the job nicely.  You should be able to rent one and a portable generator to power it from a local tool rental shop.  They should be able to fix you up with the correct tool for the job.

Comment: I made it. By using jack hammer bauer.

Answer (score 1):

Drill a hole and blow it up (cheapest method). Once a crack has been formed, you could remove it with a hammer and a chisel. A relatively cheap firecracker can do the job. Sounds stup1d but in enclosed spaces the amount of pressure released by a firecracker could be enough to at least form a crack in the concrete.

Comment: They sell expanding compounds for the explosive-averse.

Comment: Is it against any law in US? Not sure where to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

The fire cracker idea sounds more fun than my idea, but I'd simply dig out the concrete and remove it whole. If you're lucky they only used 40lbs, that's not that bad. Once the concrete is unsupported by the soil, it should crack a bit easier for disposal.